# GitHub - reset local branch and pull new changes

Tags: bash, git, github

I cloned a repository and checked out specific branch and start editing one file.

My friend also cloned and checked out the same branch and start editing the same file.

We then troubleshoot together on his computer and confirm that everything is working.
He then pushed all changes to the same branch.

How do I properly reset/cancel all my changes (of the same branch) and just pull new ones? 
(the ones that he pushed)

Answer (score 2):

You can first discard all your changes

```
git reset --hard
```

Then you can pull his version of the branch that he pushed

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I properly reset/cancel all my changes and just pull new ones?
> (the ones that he pushed)

There are few options:

#### Delete the local branch and check it out again:

```
# delete your local changes
git branch -D <branch name>

# fetch the changes or checkout the branch
git fetch --all --prune

# now checkout out the desired branch again
git checkout <branch>
```

#### Reset to any given point

```
# "remove" all your changes from the tip of the branch
# see the next section on how to get the required SHA-1
git reset <SHA-1> --hard

# grab the changes from the remote
git pull origin <branch>
```

#### How to find the last common commit?

```
# Get latest changes from the remote
git fetch --all --prune

# find the last "shared" commit of your 2 branches
git merge-base <branch> origin/<branch>
```

#### Check if your branches are up to date

```
# show remotes and local branches and they status against the remote
git remote show origin
```